# Converting Java program to Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, frameworks, split

I have a short program that takes a string from a console prompt, in this format:

> 1=Harry_2=Male_3=54_4=Blonde_5=French_6=Teacher

and prints it like so:

> 1 Name Harry
>
> 2 Gender Male
>
> 3 Age 54
>
> 4 Hair Blonde
>
> 5 Nationality French
>
> 6 Occupation Teacher

However, my next aim is to take this and recreate it as a program that operates from a web browser. I've read the documentation for the Spring Framework and got a demo program running, but I'm at a loss as to how to begin taking my script and fitting it to the framework.

Ideally, I'd like to have a single page with an input box which prints the results underneath.

Any advice on how to begin this process would be great.

Oh, the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class maptest { 
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException { 
        
        Map<String, String> tagMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
        tagMap.put("1","Name");
        tagMap.put("2","Gender");
        tagMap.put("3","Age");
        tagMap.put("4","Hair");
        tagMap.put("5","Nationality");
        tagMap.put("6","Occupation");

        String input; 
        BufferedReader reader;
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Insert raw data: ");
        input = reader.readLine();
        
        String Msg = input;
        String[] params = Msg.split("_");  
        for (String p : params) {     
            String[] nv = p.split("=");     
            String name = nv[0];     
            String value = nv[1];     
            System.out.println(nv[0] + " " + tagMap.get(nv[0]) + " " + nv[1]);} 
        
    } 
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the Spring documentation?

Comment: Hi - yes as mentioned I have read through the docs and followed the provided tutorial to get a demo program running, but unfortunately I am at a loss as to how to progress from that point..

Answer (score 0):

To mimic this in a Spring webapp, you'll want to create a Controller class that takes the input from the HTML form and transforms it to the output you like. See [Implementing Controllers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller) in the reference documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options to process the input (e.g., receive it as part of the URL, structured in a form submit) and many options to render the result (typically using HTML).

You can follow the [Spring-MVC 3 Showcase tutorial](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/07/22/spring-mvc-3-showcase/) for a simple controller and the basic notion of mapping information from requests to controllers, and from controllers to views.